# Is there a way to match only if all children matches in CSS? Or at worst make it easier to repeat n times?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Consider:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
  <style type="text/tailwindcss">
    @tailwind base; @tailwind components; @tailwind utilities; input:not(:checked) + [root]:has( + div input:checked + [child] ~ input:checked + [child] ~ input:checked + [child] ~ input:checked + [child] ~ input:checked + [child] ~ input:checked + [child]
    ~ input:checked + [child] ) { @apply bg-purple-400; } input:checked + [child] ~ input:checked + [child] ~ input:checked + [child] ~ input:checked + [child] ~ input:checked + [child] ~ input:checked + [child] ~ input:checked + [child] { outline: 2px
    solid black; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-slate-400 p-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="parent1" class="[&:checked+label]:bg-green-700" />
    <label root for="parent1" class="flex h-6 w-6 bg-blue-700">
    <span class="sr-only">Enable</span>
  </label>

    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="child1" class="[&:checked+label]:bg-green-400" />
      <label child for="child1" class="flex h-6 w-6 bg-blue-400">
      <span class="sr-only">Enable</span>
    </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="child2" class="[&:checked+label]:bg-green-400" />
      <label child for="child2" class="flex h-6 w-6 bg-blue-400">
      <span class="sr-only">Enable</span>
    </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="child3" class="[&:checked+label]:bg-green-400" />
      <label child for="child3" class="flex h-6 w-6 bg-blue-400">
      <span class="sr-only">Enable</span>
    </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="child4" class="[&:checked+label]:bg-green-400" />
      <label child for="child4" class="flex h-6 w-6 bg-blue-400">
      <span class="sr-only">Enable</span>
    </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="child5" class="[&:checked+label]:bg-green-400" />
      <label child for="child5" class="flex h-6 w-6 bg-blue-400">
      <span class="sr-only">Enable</span>
    </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="child6" class="[&:checked+label]:bg-green-400" />
      <label child for="child6" class="flex h-6 w-6 bg-blue-400">
      <span class="sr-only">Enable</span>
    </label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="child7" class="[&:checked+label]:bg-green-400" />
      <label child for="child7" class="flex h-6 w-6 bg-blue-400">
      <span class="sr-only">Enable</span>
    </label>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I was trying to figure out if now that we have new selectors like *:has*, *:is*, and *:where*. I can apply a style only if all children matches a selector.

In the example below, I hard coded the items to only change color if all the child checkboxes were checked.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZUTTcRJf2R?file=css

But I could not find a way to match only for all. Only by repeating the selectors as many times as needed. which is not great.

Is there a way to at least make this less painful with something like a macro or even an utility?

FYI, this is just out of curiosity for CSS. **I am** ***not*** **looking for a JavaScript solution.**

Comment: Playground links are nice to have, but you still need to include your code directly in the question. Please do so and submit your question for review.

Comment: The downfall of the library in use - class based and not pure CSS

Comment: This isn't possible without javascript.

Comment: @OuroBorus It is but you need to add a selector for each and every children, as it is in the example, this can be automated but still too much trouble for something so small.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to imply "in the general case". However, I just thought of a way this might be do-able: Set your base color to the all-checked color, then use something like `:has([type="checkbox"]:not(:checked))` to set it to the not-all-checked color. Not sure if that would work and it may need tweaking.

Comment: holy molly, It does work and I have no idea why and how, if they open the question please reply as answer and I will accept.  Let me know if have any idea why this works. The full selector is: "input:not(:checked)
  + [root]:not(:has(
    + div
      input:not(:checked)
      + [child]
  )) {
  background-color: pink;"

Comment: in case you need to see it in action: https://play.tailwindcss.com/pdMFnkePoC